# SQLite database locked for writing on Azure Linux but not on Windows

Tags: sqlite, entity-framework-core, azure-web-app-service

I'm using EF Core 6.0 with SQLite in a production application. That has been working perfectly in Azure Windows for years. Yesterday, I migrated this same app to Azure Linux with .NET 6.0. Surprisingly, the DB locks on update and nothing can be changed.

I have isolated the issue to a basic `DELETE` operation:

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("DELETE FROM Table WHERE ID = 1")
```

In Azure Windows and in my local machine works great. In a newly created Azure Linux web app, if fails with an error

> SqliteException: SQLite Error 5: 'database is locked'

Exactly the same code and settings.

The data source was already reduced to a minimum - "Data Source=...file"

The application can successfully write in the database folder. The database file has write permission.

Not sure what else can be done...

Is EF Core behavior different in Windows and Linux?

Answer (score 3):

Apparently /home is mounted as CIFS filesystem which can not deal with SQLite3 lock. github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/47130

Was able to find a solution by changing to WAL mode and using polling:

1 - Open the DB locally and execute:

```
PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;
```

2 - Upload the DB back to the site.

3 - Use Pooling=True on the connection string. Example:

```
Data Source={DbFilePath};Pooling=True;
```

Comment: You may want to read that article for better understanding https://www.sqlite.org/useovernet.html